# How to calculate the complexity of this loop?

Tags: complexity-theory

What is the complexity of this loop? I can't wrap my head around it.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
    for (j = i; j < n; ++j) {
        for (k = 0; k < j; ++k) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: It's an infinite loop because the 2nd loop increments `i` instead of `j`.

Comment: Replace `// Do something` with a trace statement and increase `n`. Notice how many trace statements have been printed. You should be able to see a very clear pattern after trying `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: @DanAbramov I love proof by observation :-)

Comment: Once you get code that doesn't infinite loop, look at a graph of the number of `// Do something`s as a function of `n`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the second increment should be ++j, not ++i. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`O(n^3)`, I believe. See [Square pyramidal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number).

`i` loop has `n` iterations.

`j` loop: (1 + 2 + ... + n), starting with `n` iterations, and finishing with `1`.

`k` loop: (1² + 2² + ... n²), `j` times per each iteration of the `j` loop.

And finally:

[image]